# Laravel which route group does current route belong to

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am working with `Laravel 5.5` and want to find out if the current route belongs to the `auth:web` middleware group. Is there a way to get this?

My routes:

```
/***********************************************************************************************************************
 * Guest routes
 **********************************************************************************************************************/
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['guest']
], function () {

    Route::get("login", "Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm")->name("user.login");
    Route::post("login", "Auth\LoginController@login")->name("user.do-login");
..................    
});

/***********************************************************************************************************************
 * All routes that require AUTH
 **********************************************************************************************************************/
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:user']
], function () {
..............
});
```

Something like below. Note I want the `route group` not the `auth` for the `user`:

```
$request()->currentRoute()->isGuest();
```

Is this possible? I cannot seem to find this in the `Laravel` docs.

I am trying to achieve executing a popup modal on all `guest` route pages without having to check and maintain a list of routes to test against. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `handle` method in the guest middleware class `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`, something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    // share a token to all views for this middleware:
    View::share('is_guest_route', true);  // <-- this line is added

    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Make sure to also add:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

in the use-section of the file.

Now, in every view (blade file), you can do:

```
@if (isset($is_guest_route))
    // do whatever is needed for guest routes
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it with workaround. Added `web.` or `app.` prefix to all route names and now I search for this.

```
@if(substr(\Request::route()->getName(), 0, 4) !== 'web.')
    @include('org.popupmsg.modal-pop')
@endif
```

with now the routes having changed to: `web.user.login`

Comment: A route name should never have to be changed. Therefore, this may not be the right place for a distinction between middlewares. You might regret prefixing the route names each time you want to change the set of middlewares for a route.